# Extract the n-th elements from sublists of list and combine them in a new list?

Tags: scala

Given `List[List[Any]]`, how can I reduce it to `List[Any]` that would contain n-th elements of each sublist?
Let me explain it with an example. This is the initial list:

```
List(List(1,2,3,44),List(2,3,4,55))
```

I want to extract 4-th elements from `List(1,2,3,44)` and `List(2,3,4,55)` in order to get:

```
List(44,55)
```

Should Ithe  use `reduce` or should I combine `map` with `flatten` or something? Any hint would be very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lift each sublist to a partial function, where list positions not defined are mapped to `None`, and defined positions to `Some(listValue)`, and use `flatMap` to flatten out onto a list,

```
xs.flatMap(_.lift(3))
res1: List[Int] = List(44, 55)

xs.flatMap(_.lift(4))
res2: List[Int] = List()
```

Comment: If one of resulting lists always contains 1 elements e.g. List(1), how to reduc it safely to a single value? I suppose that  `xs.flatMap(_.lift(4)).head(0)` is not safe

Comment: Use `headOption`, e.g. `xs.flatMap(_.lift(4)).headOption` delivers `None`.

Answer (score 0):

What did you try?

Something like

```
val ll = List(List(1,2,3,44),List(2,3,4,55))
ll.map(_.apply(3))
```

just works.

As long as you extract single element, your result is already flatten.

Comment: I tried many different combinations like `ll.get.head(3)` which takes only first sub-list, or `ll.map.(_._4)` which cannot compile, etc. I didn't know about `apply` function.

Comment: `list.apply(n)` == `list(n)` == `return n-th element, or throw java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`. You can also use `list.lift(n)` to get `Option` as a result and avoid exception.

Comment: The usage of `lift` seems to be a safer solution. Thanks.

Comment: Note that passing an "out of bounds" index `n` to `_.apply(n)` will result in an exception. `ll.map(_.apply(999)) ... java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 999`

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
list.map(_(3))
```

but this is not quite safe: if your sublists does not have enough elements, you'll get IndexOutOfBoundsException

More safe solution is:

```
list.flatten(_.lift(3))
```